# Using Promises / Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, facebook, mongodb, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to find a way/best way to use promises in my Node application.
I'll be honest, I don't 100% understand promises, but I'm getting better with more practice.

What I'm currently looking to do is after someone logs in:

1. Get a facebook access token
2. Access the users profile, update the user document in Mongodb or create a new user document if they don't exist
3. Access facebook friends list and cross reference a "friends" document in Mongodb.

Problem I have is to do point 3, I require the access token from point 1 AND the user document either existing or newly created in point 2 to pass into the third function.

My chain of functions looks like:

```
getAccessToken(req)
.then(function(accessToken){
 getUserProfile(req, accessToken)
 .then(findUser.bind(null, req, res))
  .then(...)
 });
```

getAccessToken returns "accessToken" from Facebook.
getUserProfile returns the user from Facebook.
findUser finds existing or creates new user Document in Mongodb.

How do I return the existing or newly created user object and pass it through coupled with the accessToken in the form of a promise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either nest promises:

```
getAccessToken(req)
.then(function(accessToken) {
  return getUserProfile(req, accessToken)
  .then(findUser.bind(null, req, res))
  .then(function(user) {
    // use accessToken & user
  })
});
```

Or store resolved values in the outer scope:

```
var _accessToken;
getAccessToken(req)
.then(function(accessToken) {
  _accessToken = accessToken;
  return getUserProfile(req, accessToken);
})
.then(findUser.bind(null, req, res))
.then(function(user) {
    // use _accessToken & user
});
```

Remember to always return the nested promise.